# почему javax.swing.JComponent унаследован от java.awt.Container

Tags: java, swing, awt

Изучаю Swing по книге Ивана Портянкина *"Swing эффективные пользовательские интерфейсы, 2-е издание"*.

Прочитал, что легковесные компоненты Swing основаны на тяжеловесных компонентах AWT. Все было понятно.. вроде как компоненты AWT зависят от ОС, а в Swing только контейнеры верхнего уровня зависят от ОС, а все остальные компоненты - это просто область в пространстве контейнера верхнего уровня и от ОС они уже не зависят. Но в той же книге написано, что класс `javax.swing.JComponent`, который как раз и является родителем всех этих легковесных компонентов унаследован от `java.awt.Container`, который, как я понял, является тяжеловесным?

Как так получилось, что легковесные компоненты пошли от тяжеловесных? Или это сделано, чтобы у компонентов Swing были те же самые методы, что и компонентов AWT? И там как-то так все хитро поменяли, что компоненты Swing стали легковесными? Не могу вот этого понять.

Всем заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загляните в исходный код `java.awt.Component`. Там можно увидеть поле `ComponentPeer peer`, которое, для тяжелых компонентов, таких как `java.awt.Button`, содержит ссылку на реализацию `java.awt.ComponentPeer`. Реализация зависит от платформы, на которой запущена JVM, и работает непосредственно с "тяжелым" объектом. Для "легких" объектов используется реализация `java.awt.LightweightPeer`.

Методы `java.awt.Component` делегируют исполнение действий, типа установки цвета или текста, этому `peer` ([шаблон проектирования "Мост"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)). Таким образом, иерархия классов сама по себе свободна от нативного кода и тяжелых компонентов, и только некоторые ее члены из пакета `java.awt` используют нативные реализации.

Общая иерархия выстроена, скорее всего, потому, что Swing зависит от AWT в части работы с событиями операционной системы (мышь, клавиатура, перерисовка), буфером обмена, управлением фокусом и т.п. Контейнер верхнего уровня (`JFrame` и т.п.), на котором размещаются все остальные компоненты, так же использует AWT. Так же общая иерархия позволяет совместно использовать Swing и AWT компоненты.

**Обновление:**

Попробую на примере `java.awt.Component.setForeground(Color c)`. Для кнопок метод устанавливает цвет текста. Метод определен в `java.awt.Component` как:

```
public void setForeground(Color c) {
    Color oldColor = foreground;
    ComponentPeer peer = this.peer;
    foreground = c;
    if (peer != null) {
        c = getForeground();
        if (c != null) {
            peer.setForeground(c);
        }
    }
    // This is a bound property, so report the change to
    // any registered listeners.  (Cheap if there are none.)
    firePropertyChange("foreground", oldColor, c);
}
```

В коде новый цвет присваивается полю `Component.foreground`, и, если есть `peer`, вызывается `peer.setForeground`. Метод пира для "тяжелого" компонента в реализации под Windows можно посмотреть на [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WComponentPeer.java#WComponentPeer.setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29), он берет цвет в виде `int` и вызывает нативный метод. Для "легкого" компонента используется реализация `sun.awt.NullComponentPeer` интерфейса `LightweightPeer`, который [ничего не делает](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/NullComponentPeer.java#NullComponentPeer). Так же создается событие об изменении поля и рассылается всем слушателям.

Дальше, по пути к `javax.swing.JButton` метод `setForeground` переопределяется в `JComponent` следующим образом:

```
public void setForeground(Color fg) {
    Color oldFg = getForeground();
    super.setForeground(fg);
    if ((oldFg != null) ? !oldFg.equals(fg) : ((fg != null) && !fg.equals(oldFg))) {
        // foreground already bound in AWT1.2
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Т.е. сперва выполняется метод класса `Component`, в котором новый цвет присваивается полю, пир ничего не делает, и отправляется событие. Затем, если цвет изменился, запрашивается перерисовка занимаемого компонентом места, через Swing-овский `RepaintManager` (цепочка из `Component.repaint()` вызывающего `JComponent.repaint(long, int, int, int, int)` по переопределению).

Теперь о том, где берется пир. Для `java.awt.Button` пир получается в

```
public void addNotify() {
    synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
        if (peer == null)
            peer = getToolkit().createButton(this);
        super.addNotify();
    }
}
```

`addNotify` вызывается, когда компоненты подготавливаются к отображению, например, когда для базового окна вызывается `pack()` или `setVisible(true)`. `getToolkit()` возвращает реализацию для текущей платформы ([`sun.awt.windows.WToolkit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#WToolkit.createButton%28java.awt.Button%29) для Windows), `createButton` создает пира для кнопки. Т.к. пользователь мог вызвать `setForeground` до того, как пир был создан, при его создании `foreground` копируется.

Для компонентов, не переопределивших `addNotify`, или не создавших пира, и вызвавших `super.addNotify`, внутри `Component.addNotify` вызывается [`java.awt.Toolkit.createComponent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Toolkit.java#Toolkit.createComponent%28java.awt.Component%29), возвращающий `NullComponentPeer`.

Comment: Получается что в java.awt.Component ссылка на ComponentPeer ссылается на объект который действительно реализует интерфейс ComponentPeer а в javax.swing.JComponent тоже ведь наследуется эта ссылка, потому что он хоть не напрямую но наследован от класс Component но теперь она ссылается на объект который реализует интерфейс LightWeightPeer который наследован от ComponentPeer, поэтому возможно так сделать. И за счёт этого и обеспечивается легковесность компонентов Swing?

Comment: Скорее это подключаемая "тяжеловесность". Если компонент использует нативную реализацию, `peer` - ссылка на эту реализацию, и этой реализации делегируется часть методов. Вообще, так сделано не столько для возможности делать легкие (не связанные с нативными) компоненты, сколько для удобства использования разных библиотек компонентов на разных платформах (через фабрики `java.awt.Toolkit`).

Comment: А можно на примере пожалуйста? Вот классы Button и JButton. Оба наследуются от Component, напрямую или косвенно, но наследуются. Как так получается, что Button тяжеловесный,а JButton легковесный?

Comment: дополнил примером

Comment: спасибо, все очень понятно изложено! Один момент только остался.. Как метод setForeground может быть вызван до того как пир был создан? Разве Пир не отвечает за отрисовку компонента? Как же компонент может быть создан раньше пира (а ведь что бы вызвать метод setForeground компонент уже должен быть создан)?

Comment: И еще один вопрос: правда ли что классом WToolkit, как и любым другим классом, определенным в пакете sun, можно пользоваться только если я использую реализацию java от Oracle?

Comment: Данные дублируются. Если пир есть, то при установке значения, ему передадут. Если нет, то потом, в процессе создания пира, значения будут скопированы.

Comment: Вообще не рекомендовано использовать напрямую классы из `sun.*`, т.к. нет гарантий, что их API не изменится/сами классы там останутся. Как все устроено в разных реализациях java я понятия не имею; В данном случае рискну предположить, что будет своя реализация `java.awt.Toolkit`.

Comment: я понял, спасибо большое! А можно как-нибудь залезть в классы из sun.* и посмотреть как они написаны? в src.zip они не хранятся. Наверняка хранятся в одном из .jar файлов в папке jdk или jre, но я не знаю в каком. Нагуглить где же они хранятся я не смог. Вот здесь только сказано что их надо скачивать отдельно: http://javatalks.ru/topics/19590.php&highlight=  Но как так может быть?  Ведь что бы компоненты отрисовывались, эти классы уже должны присутствовать, разве нет? Или пытаться залезть в эти классы вообще глупое занятие?

Comment: Исходники jdk открыты, в тексте ответа есть ссылки на grepcode, где можно их в браузере смотреть